# Change Height of layout smooth

Tags: android

I have searched and tryed few methods of how to change height of a view with a smooth animation. The easiest way I found and most convenient was this one:

```
 ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                mainLayout.getMeasuredHeight(), mainLayout.getMeasuredHeight() - mediaController.getMeasuredHeight() - conv.toPixels(20),
                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                        musicListLayout.setAnimation(scaleAnimation);
                        musicListLayout.startLayoutAnimation();
```

However this method doesn't work and I don't know why. I have tryed few more but I would like to make this one work or find another one that will.

I have  a Playlist that have `( WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT )` and when I play on a song me `MediaController` shows up, I want to translate/animate the `RecyclerView` and the `MediaController` to change theyr dimension to fit on the screen.

Thank's for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easiest way (API>11, I think): change height directly, with no animation at all, and set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` on the parent view in your layout.

To change the animation duration, try calling `container.getLayoutTransition().setDuration(duration)` where `container` is the above mentioned parent view.

Comment: It should be really smooth, from my experience. What issues are you facing?

Comment: Nevermind it's ok, I wanted to make the transition in more time like 2 seconds but the transition of mediacontroller is too fast.

Comment: @natario : I did exactly what u said , change the height with no animation gives heavy jerking effect